# How do I get Java to read a list of numbers from a text?

Tags: java

How do I get my Java code to read the next number from a list of numbers in a text file. My output repeats the first number multiple times, how do I fix this?

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
    for (int l = 0; l < 9; l++) {
        java.io.File myfile;
        String mypath;
        mypath = "/Users/tonyg/Downloads";
        myfile = new java.io.File(mypath + "/file.txt");
        Scanner myinfile = new Scanner(myfile);
        int val1;
        val1 = myinfile.nextInt();
        System.out.println(val1);
    }
}
```

OUTPUT:

385

385

385

385

385

385

385

385

385

Comment: Try using a debugger? Your development environment can step through this code, and allow you to observe in slow motion what your program is doing wrong.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like your initializing the Scanner on every iterations of the for loop by simply initializing before the loop, your issue should be resolved. It's also best practice to [close the Scanner](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29865150/how-do-i-close-a-scanner-in-java/29865351) after using the resource

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
    java.io.File myfile;
    String mypath;
    mypath = "/Users/tonyg/Downloads";
    myfile = new java.io.File(mypath + "/file.txt");
    Scanner myinfile = new Scanner(myfile);
    for (int l = 0; l < 9; l++) {
        int val1;
        val1 = myinfile.nextInt();
        System.out.println(val1);
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

1. Initialize `Scanner` out of loop
2. Catch `FileNotFoundException`
3. Combine declaration and initialization of variables (in this particular case)
4. Use clear *camelCase* identifiers for your variables
5. Avoid using `l` (lowercase `L`) as a variable identifier. In many fonts `l` (lowercase `L`)  and `1` (digit one) look similar. This may lead to future bugs caused by typos.
6. Close your `Scanner` in the end

(#1, #2 and #6 can be achieved by using `try-with-resources`)

```
String dirPath = "/Users/tonyg/Downloads";
String filePath = dirPath + "/file.txt";
int count = 9;

try(Scanner scanner = new Scanner(new File(filePath))){
    for (int i = 0; i < count; i++) {
        int value = scanner.nextInt();
        System.out.println(value);
    }
} catch (FileNotFoundException e){
    // Print stack-trace or do something else
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```